# Segurança dos Dados/Acesso no Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)

Tags: visual-studio, segurança, microsoft, visual-studio-online

Tenho acesso ao **Visual Studio Team Services** (www.meudominio.visualstudio.com) e a principio utilizo como segurança somente o aplicativo **[Microsoft Authenticator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.azure.authenticator&hl=pt_BR)** , ou seja, **[verificação de duas etapas da Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/12408/microsoft-account-about-two-step-verification)**.

Teria alguma outra alternativa para garantir mais segurança e dificultar o acesso à conta do VSTS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você já tomou todas as medidas possíveis para inibir o acesso ao **seu usuário**. Quando a segurança a sua conta, isso é garantido pela própria Microsoft, tendo em vista que a Microsoft investe pesado em segurança em sua plataforma de nuvem, onde ela tem diversas [certificações em segurança](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/trustcenter/compliance/default.aspx).

Pode ficar tranquilo, pois é muito pouco provável uma violação de segurança em sua conta do VSTS, eu poderia dizer que é muito mais seguro você manter seus dados no VSTS do que em um ambiente OnPremisses com o TFS, onde muitas vezes a empresa pode ter um numero maior de brechas na rede e não saber disso.